# Objective c syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I am new to Objective-C programming. In many tutorials I have been seeing code with this format:

```
[[classname function] function];
```

For example:

```
[[NSString alloc] initwithformat:parameters];
```

When I was learning about plist and dictionaries I saw this line of code:

```
[[self.objname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"somename"];
```

I believe it follows the syntax: `[[objectname function] function]`

Can someone please explain how this syntax works and the difference between the first and second example.

Also it would be really helpful if you can provide the equivalent statements in C or Java for these examples.

Comment: We will assume that mkb's edits are what the OP meant, since the original syntax was illegal (`[classname function] function]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[ClassName methodName]` is how you call a class method. The equivalent in Java is `Classname.methodName();`

`[object methodName]` is how you call a normal instance method. The equivalent in Java is `object.methodName();`

In Objective C you can also 'nest' calls in `[]` brackets. `[[Classname method1] method2]` is equivalent to calling the class method `method1`, which returns some object and *then* calling `method2` on that object.

The equivalent in Java would be `Classname.method1().method2();`

Also note that in strict Objective C terminology you don't 'call a method on an object', you 'send a message to an object' instead. Same thing, different words.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a shorthand notation that avoids creating transitory variables or objects. You can nest as many of these as you want, but you should keep the code readable.

E.g. if you have an array of strings that are image names, to get the image you could do this:

```
NSString *imageName = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

If you want to do without the `NSString` variable, you can write:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray onjectAtIndex:0]];
```

Clear?

Answer (score 0):

[self.objname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"somename"]; is basically doing this:

There's a dictionary in an array (array being objname) and you target the dictionary with objectAtIndex. Next the dictionary contains a number of key's and value's for those keys. You target a value by doing objectForKey:id.

Somewhat lengthier simpler syntax would be:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [objname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey@"key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first. The `[[obj method1] method2]` variant sends the `method1` message to `obj` and then sends the `method2` message to the return value of `[obj method1]`.

The second example, `[[self.objname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"somename"]` is a little bit more complex. `self.objname` is an access to the property `objname` of the object `self` (self refers always to the own object instance). So with `[self.objname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` the message `objectAtIndex` is send to the object returned by `self.objname`, with the parameter `indexPath.row`. `indexPath` is, again, an object and you access the property `row`. And on THAT return value you send the message `objectForKey` with the parameter `@"somename"`. And @"str" is the built-in syntax for objective-c strings.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The . format is a shorthand for a get method. So, for example, if a person object has an age, and you have a getAge method defined (or synthesized), you can call [person getAge] or person.age and get equivalent results.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the brackets mean that you are sending a message to an object. If the message returns a value that is also an object, you can also send that object a message. The inner message of your first example sends the message `alloc` to the class object `NSString`. This returns a pointer to an allocated object of type `NSString`. The `initWithFormat:` message then initializes the contents of the string.

In Java, this would be something like:

```
public class NSString {
  public static NSString alloc() {
    return new byte[<size of a string>];
  }
  public void initWithParameters(Map<String, String> params) {
    /* initialize */
  }
}
```

and in some other file:

```
NSString str = NSString.alloc().initWithParameters(params);
```

but Java's object model is not quite the same as Objective-C, so this is only an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your confusion is over dot-notation, since this often confuses new developers. It was an awkward and recent addition to the language. I will also assume that mkb's edits are correct, since your original code wasn't legal.

This call:

```
[[self.objname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"somename"];
```

Is precisely the same as this call:

```
[[[self objname] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"somename"];
```

It's rough likely equivalent in a language like C++ would be this:

```
this.objname.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("somename");
```

This is a rough equivalence, because ObjC and C++ have different approaches to how methods are called, but in most cases these would be the same.

You may be interested in [Learning Cocoa with other backgrounds](http://robnapier.net/blog/learning-cocoa-2-467). I also strongly recommend [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) as a start, or a solid book on the subject. Objective-C is very different from Java and C++, and in my experience, trying to pick it up as you go will lead to significant confusion and frustration later. It is best to learn the language in its own terms rather than trying to figure out "how do I do this C++ thing in ObjC?" Half the time the answer is: you don't.